# How to export SQL server compact 3.5 database (or view the "Create table")

Tags: export, sql-server-ce, create-table

I have a SQL server compact 3.5 database  (.sdf) and I would like to use it to recreate the same schema in a new SQL server database. So my question is: Is it possible to export the structure of my tables somehow?

Ideally, the result would be an SQL file with lot of "Create table..." that I could use to create a similar database. I don't need to export the data as this stage.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox (VS add-in or standalone) - http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Looks like there is no download link for 3.5 Only 4.0. And that version 2.1.3.0 doesn't let me add a SQL server compact 3.5 connection...

Comment: Sorry, only the VS add-in supports 3.5, but my Exportsqlce.exe command line tool works with 3.5 - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Exportsqlce.exe returns the error: "Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'" I'm on windows 7 64-bit. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you must install both the 3.5 SP2 x86 and x64 runtimes on x64 systems

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned at: http://bembengarifin-tech.blogspot.in/2008/08/generate-script-export-data-from-sql-ce.html

And you'll have to download Export2SQLCE.exe and follow the command and it'll generate data with schema & data also.

Hope this helps.